# Code should replace hex with decimal but after first hex value is found it moves to the next line

Tags: python, loops, replace

I am trying to write the code that reads through a text file and replace each instance of a hex number with the decimal equivalent.  The problem is that once a hex value is found, the code moves to the next line.  So, if there are multiple hex values on a one-line, only the first one gets converted.  I am a newbie to coding and I got this far by reading other questions/answers, but I don't know how to make it loop over each line until it has converted all the hex values.  Thank you for your help.

'''

```
with open(inFileName, 'r') as inFile:
   with open(outFileName, 'w') as outFile:
      for line in inFile:
         if re.search("0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+",line): # Use regex to search the line for a hex value
            hex = re.search("0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+",line).group() # Get the hex value            
            dec = int(hex,16) # Convert hex to dec
            line_dec = line.replace(hex,str(dec)) # Replace the hex with the dec in the line
            outFile.write(line_dec)
        else:
            outFile.write(line)
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using search, try using re.findall

```
import re
line = "0x2 another number 0xF and another 0xA"

hex_vals = re.findall("0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+", line)
print(hex_vals) # ['0x2', '0xF', '0xA']    

for h in hex_vals:
    decimal = int(h, 16)
    line.replace(h, decimal)
```

Comment: Thanks!  That helped me get there.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code could look like (using something similar to do-while):

```
actual_fragment = line
found_match = re.search("0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+",line)
prepared_fragment = ""
while found_match is not None:
     hex = found_match.group() # Get the hex value
     dec = int(hex,16) # Convert hex to dec
     prepared_fragment += actual_fragment[:found_match.start()] + str(dec) # Replace the hex with the dec in the line
     actual_fragment = actual_fragment[found_match.end():]
     #Very important:
     found_match = re.search("0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+",actual_fragment)
prepared_fragment += actual_fragment
outFile.write(prepared_fragment)
```